# How to Add Followers Into The Recipient Field of an Email in Odoo?

Tags: email, templates, automation, odoo

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025 and I'm trying to add the followers of each ticket made in helpdesk into an automated email whenever it has been changed (not only in stage). So far I've tried some codes and managed to put the followers' emails into the body of the text, but in the recipient field.

Here is the code I used:

`% for follower in object.message_follower_ids:${follower.email_formatted}%endfor`

I can use it in the body text but I can't produce any result in the Email To field. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `${str(object.message_partner_ids.ids).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')}` in "To (Partners)" field.

Comment: I still can't access the email, since I need to access the email address of each id. I've tried changing it to ```${str(object.message_partner_ids.email_formatted).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')}``` but it failed to execute. Thanks for the answer tho~

Comment: Why do you need to access the email directly? Odoo will handle this for field "To (Partners)" by itself when sending the mail. The other field expecting a list of comma separated email adresses would be "To (Emails)" and it's a bit more complicated for your requirement.

Comment: Oh, right, right. I made a mistake and put it in the "To (Emails". My bad, my bad. Yeah, that works now~ Thanks a bunch~

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but can I filter the followers so that it will only put the non-customer ones?

Comment: I tried two possibilities but both didn't work. Maybe it's better to create a computed field on `mail.thread` where those partners are already filtered.

Comment: Gotcha, will try to do that. Thanks anyway~ It was very helpful~